# How to get key of service from dependency injection?

Tags: .net-core

I have two classes A and B, A depend on B. I want to add both of them as keyed services by providing service key "dynamically" (as a variable, not constant). And if class A is added with service key "abc" then I want it to inject class B with same key. How I can achieve that? Is it possible to somehow get "current" service key? If not possible through attribute then maybe it's possible to use `IServiceProvider` to get "current" key and then inject service in constructor manually?

```cs
class A
{
    private readonly B _b;

    // how to get current service key of A and use it to inject B with same key?
    public A([FromKeyedServices("how to get key here?")] B b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }
}

class B {}

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddKeyedA(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, string serviceKey)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddKeyedSingleton<A>(serviceKey);
        serviceCollection.AddKeyedSingleton<B>(serviceKey);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not direct way to handle it, but you can inject `key` into constructor(as you also expected) using `[ServiceKey] string serviceKey`, then also inject `IServiceProvider provider` so your code will look

```cs
public A([ServiceKey] string serviceKey, IServiceProvider provider)
{
    _b = provider.GetRequiredKeyedService<B>(serviceKey);
}
```

**Important note**: `serviceKey` type is `object`, but we have to inject it using `string`(original type, not base type) due to [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/93438)

One downside of this approach is you have to call `GetRequiredKeyedService` for each service manually instead of get service just injected (but this seems fine for you)

---

Other way to achieve what you want is to provide `implementationFactory` to `AddKeyedSingleton`, and there is you will get `key` in the factory, so `AddKeyedA` will look like

```cs
public static void AddKeyedA(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, string serviceKey)
{
    serviceCollection.AddKeyedSingleton<A>(serviceKey,
        (provider, key) => new A(provider.GetRequiredKeyedService<B>(key)));
    serviceCollection.AddKeyedSingleton<B>(serviceKey);
}
```

Then your `A` service will be without `FromKeyedServices` at all and it should look

```cs
public class A
{
    private readonly B _b;

    public A(B b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }
}
```

One downside that I see for this approach is when someone add somewhere else class `A` without `factory` among with `B` without `keyed` as `A` constructor will allow create new instance with any `B` object. It can be mitigated with small(ugly) workaround, as we provided own `factory` for `A` we can change constructor to

```cs
public A([FromKeyedServices("key-that-should-never-exist")] B b)
{
    _b = b;
}
```

Other downside for this is we have to manually find all required services, so when other parameter has `FromKeyedServices` we have to use reflection and find expected `key` if it's not the same(or shouldn't be), for example

```cs
public A(B b, [FromKeyedServices("other-key-than-A-or-B")] C c)
{
    _b = b;
}
```